# How to fix "warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]"

Tags: c

So  basically the function searches a file for the '\t' (tab) character and when it finds it, its suppose to replace it with a '^I'

Problem is `c = '^I'` produces a warning `warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]`. The other problem is only the I shows up not the ^.

If I change it to `c = "^I"` I get this warning "Warning: Assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast". This way also puts "\\" instead of ^I

How can I solve this? Is there a better way to do it?

```
if ((fileContents = fopen("fileContents.txt", "r")) == 0) 
{
    perror("fopen");
    return 1; 
}

while ((c = fgetc(fileContents)) != EOF)
{

    if (c == '\t')
    {
        c = '^I';
    }
    putchar(c); 
}
```

Comment: well, use pragma warning directive. Get rid of `-Wmultichar` You are doing w/e you are doing - wrong.

Comment: @Malina uh, that is a bad idea.

Comment: `^I` are two characters, the single `''` quote can only be used to represent one character. Escaped symbols like `\t` count as a single character, as this is equivalent to a single character.

Answer (score 1):

You can not put two characters in a character literal.
`'^I'` here, there are two characters - `^` and `I`.
This is responsible for the warning:

> multi-character character constant

not sure what are you trying to achieve here, but in C you can only put single [ASCII character](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif) or [character escape sequence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) in single quotes. the `^` is system-specific ANSI escape code I think for terminal color, supported by DOS and UNIX. You can use it in a string as far as you have it declared somewhere with static or dynamic allocation or just use the `printf` function to print it out to the standard output stream: `printf("^I ^O test");`

---

As for the implicit declaration. I do assume that `c` is declared as an integer or some other sort of arithmetic-type. You can not assign a string literal to it, not in any manner. You can do that with the functions `strcpy` `sprintf` `strncpy` etc. In that case, `c` must have been statically or dynamically allocated. To avoid false implicit declaration make sure it is with the type of `char*` so an area of chars, where the last one is the null-terminating character. If you want to assign a string literal to a `char*` you will store it in read-only memory area.

```
char *string;

string = "^I";

printf(string);
```

---

You can turn off warnings with the pragma warning directive. Don't do that. Warnings are there for a reason.

Comment: Hi, what I'm trying to do is every time a tab ('\t') is found, it be replaced with "^I". I don't want ^I to just be printed the tabs need to be replaced.

Comment: Then your question is rather unclear. `\t` is a SINGLE character that represents the tab space while `"^I"` is string. You may want to APPEND `^` before `\t` and replace `\t` with `I`. You can use `strtok` or/and `strcat` for this. In any case you would want to build a string.

Comment: In the task-explaining comment in the other answer you mention something completely different. If you want to print `"^I"` each time `\t` is met in a string you can use a loop or a loop and `strchr`

Answer (score 1):

A `char` can only be a single character.  `'^I'` is two.  In your case you'll want to if/else on the character, printing the string using a normal `printf`

```
if (c == '\t') {
    printf("^I");
} else {
    putchar(c);
}
```

Comment: I am trying to replace tabs with "^I" this will just print out "^I" every time there is a tab.

Comment: @nb023 what's the difference? replace it how?

Answer (score 0):

`'^I'` is, quite obviously, two characters. You can't use `putchar` with multiple characters, and as gcc warns you, multi-char constants are not something you want to use.

Instead, make sure you use a string. Try something like:

```
const char *replacement = NULL;
if (c == '\t') replacement = "^I";

if (replacement) fputs(replacement, stdout);
else putchar(c);
```